# adding incremented integers to end of char array. C

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I'm trying to make a char array in "C" that would have an integer value at the end of the array. but I'm trying to change the integer value while going through a loop.

```
system("mv " + file_list[loca] + " /media/MyBook1TB/" + folderint);

file_list[n][200] // is a char array of file locations
folderint //  folder increment variable example "/media/MyBook1TB/0" then "/media/MyBook1TB/1"
```

I'm not sure if c.str() would work for what I put in system() up above.

I couldn't find anything on the cplusplus website. any help?

I'm trying to not use the string library..

Comment: why are you trying not to use the string library? and are you using c or are you using c++

Comment: fixed the tag for you then

Comment: If it's just a single character [0-9] then just put the ascii value [48-57 decimal] in the proper location.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is really not a good way to do things. What if `file_list[loca]` is `. .; rm -rf /* ; echo`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the array contents come from a text file. so im not too worried about that. plus this is a very simple program. just some parts isnt for me right now, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char system_string[LARGE_COMFORTABLE_NUM];

sprintf(system_string,"mv %s /media/MyBook1TB/%d",file_list[loca],folderint);

system(system_string);
```

Comment: I wasn't sure what the file_list[loca] was, but shanet and I are in the same ballpark.

Answer (score 3):

In C you can't just add together strings to concatenate them. You need to do something like:

```
char command[MAX_LENGTH];
sprintf(command, "mv %s /media/MyBook1TB/%d", file_list[loca], folderint);
system(command);
```

You don't specify what `file_list` is so you'll need to define your own `MAX_SIZE`. Also note that `%s` assumes `file_list` is a string and `%d` assumes that `folderInt` is an `int`.

Side note, the nature of the command you've posted seems like it would be better suited for a shell script, but if you must use C, look up the `exec` functions. `system` is a dangerous (and inefficient) function to call (especially in this case if you're not sanitizing your inputs).

Comment: I dont know how to make a shell script. i have only learned C/C++, Python, VB, and Java in college. i have never seen anyone make a script.

Comment: @Alex Shell scripts are very easy (especially compared to C!). They are essentially just a file with a list of shell commands to run. You can still create variables and use loops and conditional statements too. Look up bash scripting on Google.